# Процедуры, функции, модули. Работа с текстовыми файлами

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

1.Создать модуль на языке Pascal, содержащий:

**а) объявления типов данных (для одномерных и двумерных массивов);
б) функцию, вычисляющую значение: y=min{ab; ac; bc}
в) процедуру, реализующую следующий алгоритм: Найти среднее
арифметическое всех отрицательных элементов каждого столбца
матрицы Q(m,n).**

Вот модуль, что я написал, если он верный, то нужно сделать только задание 2.

```
unit rngl;
interface
  type massiv=array of integer;
       matrix=array[,] of integer;
function minimum(a,b,c:integer):integer;
procedure sr_arif(a:matrix;m,n:integer);    
implementation
function minimum(a,b,c:integer):integer;
begin
    if a*b<a*c then result:=a*b else result:=a*c;
    if b*c>result then result:=b*c;
end;
procedure sr_arif(a:matrix;m,n:integer); 
begin
  writeln('Средние арифметические отрицательных элементов в столбцах');  
for var j:=0 to n-1 do
 begin
    var s:real=0;
    var k:=0;
  for var i:=0 to m-1 do
      if a[i,j]<0 then
   begin   
    s+=+a[i,j]; 
    inc(k);
   end; 
  if k>0 then s/=k;       {* уменьшает значение S в k раз *}
  writeln('столбец ',j+1,'=',s:0:2);
 end;
end; 
end.
```

2. Создать программу, использующую модуль из задания 1., в которой будут
   осуществляться:
   **а) ввод исходных данных из текстового файла;
   б) обращения к процедуре и функции;
   в) вывод результатов в текстовый файл.**

Comment: *Вот модуль, что я написал, если он верный, то нужно сделать только задание 2.* Если это действительно Вы написали, то выполнение задания 2 не должно вызвать проблем. Заодно проверите, верно ли написан модуль.

Comment: я не особо уверен в правильной реализации в задании 1. б) функцию, вычисляющую значение: y=min{ab; ac; bc}

Comment: Правильно не уверены. Проверьте вручную на `a=1,b=2,c=3`.